# Passsing object with many properties to component in React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that renders a list of items that come from an API.

The return function looks like this:

```js
return (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <ItemCard
          item={item}
          isExpanded={expandedItem === item.id}
          setExpanded={toggleExpanded}
        />
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

The problem is that the item has a *single* property that is not used in the `ItemCard` component, but I can't pass its properties individually, because there are too many of them.

The `ItemCard` receives props like this:

```js
interface ItemCardProps {
  item: Item;
  isExpanded: boolean;
  setExpanded: () => void;
}


export function ItemCard({ item, isExpanded, setExpanded }: ItemCardProps) {
  return (...);
}
```

Is it okay to pass an unused property down to the component and just not worry about it? Or should I define a new object that includes only the properties that `ItemCard` will use? What's the best practice regarding passing props like this? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: There's no rule that says every component must always use every piece of information that's made available to it.  It seems semantically reasonable that an "Item Card" would display an "Item" and would thus need one provided to it.  I don't see why this would be a problem.

Comment: You're not using _any_ of the properties in `item`, or either of the other props, or even showing what the definition is. You could maybe do destructuring e.g. `{ ignoreThis, andThis, ...item }` to drop properties, whether that makes sense in your case isn't clear.

Comment: That is, in fact, why TS lets you use `?` to indicate that a property may or may not exist.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I am not showing how I use the props, because I wanted to ask for a general concept and recommendations for passing objects with more properties that component really needs and find out if it's not encouraged. I thought the implementation details are not important in this case. The component just renders smaller sub-components that use properties of `item` object. Your idea seems interesting though. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @David Thank you. So it's a matter of personal preference then? I always try to pass props individually, but this one just would be too much.

Comment: Think that every object inherits methods from `Object` and you seldom will use them :)) it's not a problem to oversatisfy a type condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may destructure the **item** into unused extra prop (**_extraProp**) and rest necessary props.
This ensures that your react component is clean.

```
 const {_extraProp, ...itemProps} = item
 return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <ItemCard
              item={itemProps}
              isExpanded={expandedItem === item.id}
              setExpanded={toggleExpanded}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
```